# Android Buttons open up the wrong activities

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-intent

I have three buttons on my main page. Something weird happens when I try to click on them. For example, when I click on the NewGame button, it first displays what the scores button should display, and then if I click the back button it will proceed to display the activity that it was meant to. With the About button, I have to click back twice (it displays the newGame activity and the scores activity. Is there a reason why this is happening?

```
public class Sakurame extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //set up click listeners for buttons
    View HighScoreButton = findViewById(R.id.highscore_button);
    HighScoreButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
        return true;
        // More items go here (if any)
    }
    return false;
}

public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.about_button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
    case R.id.new_button:
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, HighScore.class);
        startActivity(i2);
    case R.id.highscore_button:
        Intent i3 = new Intent(this, DisplayScores.class);
        startActivity(i3);
        //break;

        // more buttons go here (if any)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `break;` after each `startActivity` within the onClick method.

Edit to clarify. This ensures that once the case has been met, the `switch` statement is broken from instead of moving on to the next case statement.

```
    case R.id.about_button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.new_button:
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, HighScore.class);
        startActivity(i2);
        break;
    case R.id.highscore_button:
        Intent i3 = new Intent(this, DisplayScores.class);
        startActivity(i3);
        break;
```

Comment: Just to add clarification: Case statements cascade. So if you do not add break after each case statement, every subsequent case statement will run ...

Comment: Thank you - it solved everything. I didn't realize they cascaded @.@